# How to check if 2 large text files content are 100% same?

Tags: .net, vb.net, text-files

I have two large text files (about 1.8 GB each encoded in UTF-8). And I want to check if the content of both files are 100% same. If there is single character difference then it is considered not same, i.e. both files are different. How do I do that?

So my question is: How to check if 2 large text files content are 100% same?

```
Dim TextFile1 as String = "C:\TextFile1.log"
Dim TextFile2 as String = "C:\TextFile2.log"
```

**UPDATE:**

I forgot to add, the solution should be using minimal memory because the specific PC only has 256 mb memory

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters you can compare their size (if they're not the same size they can't have the same content). Look at the [FileInfo.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx) property for this.

If they do have the same size, you can [compare them byte by byte](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320348)

Comment: If it's text you need to compare character by character, taking encodings into account.

Comment: The code at your second link does the file size comparison as well already.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into a similar problem where I needed to identify duplicate pdf files that had the names changed. The best way to do this was by using md5 hash. 
I did a quick google search and it looks vb.net does have support built in funcationallity to do this. Check out 
http://www.vbknowledgebase.com/?Id=88&Desc=Find-Duplicate-files-using-Vb.Net-using-MD5-Hash

Comment: If you only compare two files, computing their checksum has absolutely no advantage over direct comparison.